# SAML Logout - Azure B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am trying to understand how to perform a logout in Azure B2C (I have a custom policy setup for SAML authentication), from my understanding there are two types of bindings, HTTP-Post and HTTP-Redirect. I checked the metadata file and it has both listed. I assume I can simply log-out the user by redirecting them to the URL listed is the metadata file:

`<SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://TENANT.b2clogin.com/TENANT.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_signin/samlp/sso/logout" />`

When I do that, I get a generic Azure error page:

Sorry, but we're having trouble signing you in.
We track these errors automatically, but if the problem persists feel free to contact us. In the meantime, please try again.

Why does it even say "signing you in", I am not sure. Am I doing something incorrectly here?

Is there more information I should be passing? I even tried using the post_logout_redirect_uri query string param and that doesn't work either.

Comment: Thanks @TheWebGuy and please follow this document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#single-sign-out and please let us know if still issue.

Comment: Hello @Jit_MSFT I get the same error, just to clarify I should be able to go directly to the logout page right? Since HTTP-Redirect is enabled, https://TENANT.b2clogin.com/TENANT.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_signin/samlp/sso/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=http://yahoo.com

I am not sure if any of this is useful to you internally:
Correlation ID: 25774c57-0ee7-4f2a-8d7f-36ddea67ffcc
Timestamp: 2021-04-05 16:34:41Z
AADB2C: An exception has occurred.